# async get and set

Tags: c#, asynchronous, properties

is it possible to create properties with `async` `get` and `set` methods?

if yes, how?
if no, how should I call async methods in `get` and `set` properly?

Comment: Not having an async modifier for properties is a major flaw in the C# component model. The problem lies in the inability of a property accessor to asynchronously call another method or lambda expression within the same thread as the client caller. This inability introduces various, non-trivial implementation complexities in situations where an accessor requires waitable access to async methods. Technically, get or set accessors are nothing more than separate methods and are implemented at compile-time as get_<property> and set_<property>. MSFT can and should correct this serious flaw.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. From section 10.15 of the C# 5 spec:

> A method (§10.6) or anonymous function (§7.15) with the async modifier is called an async function. In general, the term async is used to describe any kind of function that has the async modifier.

So it's only methods, lambda expressions and anonymous methods that can use the `async` modifier.

Personally I'd think it somewhat odd to have a property like that anyway, especially as the property would have had to return `Task<T>` rather than `T`. A property should usually "feel" pretty lightweight - which doesn't really fit in with async.

Comment: For the sake of anyone trying to write a responsive GUI using WPF, XAML, Windows Store apps, etc, it would be fantastic for usability to have support for async properties. One of the big reasons that MS added async/await was to free up the GUI thread, and as most GUI binding uses properties, the lack of async/await support is crippling in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

No. You can create methods which *look* like properties (`async Task<T> getFoo()` and `async Task setFoo(T item)`), but they're not properties per se.